# bail from a function after a condition was met

Tags: php, function

I've a function that do some checks and running a function accordingly.

For example, I have a class with those two functions:

```
public function printingFunction($weekly) {

    if($this-something())
        $this->shouldIPrintIt($weekly, 'Text');

    if($this->somethingElse())
        $this->shouldIPrintIt($weekly, 'Another text');

} 

private function shouldIPrintIt($weekly, $name) {

    // doing some checks

    // bail from the MAIN function printingFunction()

}
```

What I want to do that whenever the function `shouldIPrintIt()` is being triggered, it will bail out from the `printingFunction()` method. So it will skip the rest of the if conditions in it.

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: as in using `return $this->shouldIPrintIt()` ?

Comment: I think poster want's to use one return to terminate execution of several levels of function calls

Comment: Use a thrown `exception` from `shouldIPrintIt()` with a `try/catch` in the code that calls `printingFunction()`

Comment: Exceptions are clearly what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh yea! thanks a lot! I like that creative method :) However, it seems weird keeping the `catch` section with no code in it just to stop the function :) Thanks a lot guys!